# Issue with decreasing on a counter

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, counter

I am trying to make a command that adds pigs to a counter which does work but also add a command that takes it away. here is my code.

```
client.message_counter = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Bot online!")
    

@client.command()
async def add(ctx,*,amount):
    client.message_counter += int(amount)
    #await ctx.send("")
    await ctx.send(f"{client.message_counter} pigs are spotted, how many are dying?")

@client.command()
async def kill(ctx,*,amount):
  j = int(client.message_counter)
  g = int(amount)
  end = j - g

    await ctx.send(f"{g} of pigs where killed \n {end} is left")
```

The error message I'm getting looks like this

```
Ignoring exception in command kill:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 25, in kill
    end = j - g
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Here is what it looks like in discord

[image]

Comment: Looks like `amount` is being treated as string in the `kill()` function?

Comment: If `amount` is actually an integer, and you can guarantee it, you can use `g = int(amount)`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama still didn't seem to work it did help me a little more but this is what it shows me

Comment: i edited the message above to what it is currently showing and what I have added to the code to make it look that way

Comment: Did you try the same with `j` just to be 100% sure? These things are often weird, so it is good to be sure.

Comment: yeah just did, came out with the same result.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama i tried using int for other ones and I'm still having the same outcome.

Comment: Shouldn’t it just be `await ctx.send(f"{g} of pigs where killed \n {end} is left”)`?

Comment: yeah i did that before you mentioned it to me, it worked but it doesn't actually save the data when it gets subtracted, so when I added one to it it when to 601 instead of 101. @LarrytheLlama

Comment: Why are you doing `for a in {end}` though? You can just `await ctx.send(f"{g} of pigs where killed \n {end} is left”)` and then re-define client.message_counter as `end`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama I deleted all that like you said, and re-defined it, still has the same outcome of not saving the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix ;D

```py
total_pigs = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Bot online!")
    

@client.command()
async def add(ctx,*,amount):
    global total_pigs
    total_pigs += int(amount)
    await ctx.send(f"{total_pigs} pigs are spotted, how many are dying?")

@client.command()
async def kill(ctx,*,amount):
    global total_pigs
    total_pigs = int(total_pigs) - int(amount)
    await ctx.send(f"{amount} of pigs where killed \n {total_pigs} is left")
```

Here is a picture showing it:

[image: Here is pic with it]

Comment: this does work but doesn't save the information afterwords.

Comment: You can re-define `total_pigs` as `end` after  `await ctx.send(f"{amount} of pigs where killed \n {end} is left”)`

Comment: Done, now is fixed, look on edit, is that what u wanted?

Comment: Well, the issue is it doesnt save any information at all, when it says you kill them, and you add more to the pile, it doesn't actually take any away, scroll back up and view my picture for reference @Nick403